# Does "Trusty Tahr" support EFI ia32?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Does "Trusty Tahr"(*Ubuntu 14.04*) supports ia32 booting?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the pre-release images, the answer is "yes and no."

As Rinzwind has pointed out, there is a 32-bit build of the EFI version of GRUB 2 provided with Ubuntu 14.04; *however,* the `.iso` images I've seen do *not* include the necessary files to boot the Ubuntu installer on a 32-bit EFI-only computer (like a Minnowboard or some tablets). Thus, to install Ubuntu in EFI mode on such a computer, you'll need to either build your own installation medium with a working boot loader or install Ubuntu in BIOS mode (if your computer supports that) and then install an EFI boot loader afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

See package details for [grub-efi-ia32-bin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/grub-efi-ia32-bin) on Launchpad:

> Binary package “grub-efi-ia32-bin” in ubuntu trusty
>
> GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-IA32 binaries)
>
> GRUB is a portable, powerful bootloader. This version of GRUB is
> based on a  cleaner design than its predecessors, and provides the
> following new features:  .
>
> - Scripting in grub.cfg using BASH-like syntax.
> - Support for modern partition maps such as GPT.
> - Modular generation of grub.cfg via update-grub. Packages providing GRUB
>   add-ons can plug in their own script rules and trigger updates by invoking
>   update-grub.  .
>
> This package contains a version of GRUB that has been built for use with  EFI-IA32 architecture, such as the one
> provided by Intel Macs (that is, unless  a BIOS interface has been
> activated). It will not automatically install  GRUB as the active boot
> loader, nor will it automatically update grub.cfg  on upgrade, so most
> people should install [grub-efi-ia32](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/grub-efi-ia32) instead.

and package details for: [grub-efi-ia32](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/grub-efi-ia32):

> Binary package “grub-efi-ia32” in ubuntu trusty
>
> ```
> GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-IA32 version)
>
>  GRUB is a portable, powerful bootloader. This version of GRUB is based on a
>  cleaner design than its predecessors, and provides the following new features:
>  
>   - Scripting in grub.cfg using BASH-like syntax.
>   - Support for modern partition maps such as GPT.
>   - Modular generation of grub.cfg via update-grub. Packages providing GRUB
>     add-ons can plug in their own script rules and trigger updates by invoking
>     update-grub.
>  
>  This package contains a version of GRUB that has been built for use with
>  EFI-IA32 architecture, such as the one provided by Intel Macs (that is, unless
>  a BIOS interface has been activated).
> ```

So that would be: yes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and No:

- No from the installation point of view, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1025555
- Yes once the system is installed, as you can install the grub-efi-ia32 package.